# UICollectionViewCell message sent to deallocated instance right after being dequeued

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have a UICollectionViewCell which is being dequeued for reuse. I recently introduced a sliding drawer functionality which is basically a hidden view which gets displayed when the user swipes.

After the last change this seemed to create a case where the instance was being deallocated while being initialized. The exact location where the Zombie was being reported was on the call to "addGestureRecognizers()" which was being called from setupSlidingDrawer() which was in turn being called from the init function.

I have attached an image of the break point before and after the Zombie call. I have been pulling my hair all day looking at this and keep drawing a blank.

As a work around (hack) I have made the deleteView a instance variable and that seems to keep the class from releasing as the retain count is not decremented.

I feel like like the code for my collection view cell / controller is pretty standard and I am not doing anything crazy.

This seems like it is a Apple bug but I can not seem to find anything on the inter webs to prove it. If

```
class MomentsViewCell : UICollectionViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "MomentsViewCell"
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    let shareButton = UIButton()  
    var shareCallback: (() -> ())?    
    var isSwiped = false
    let overlayViewTag = 999
    var delegate: MomentsViewController?

    let shareButtonLength: CGFloat = 44

    lazy var drawerWidth: CGFloat = {
        self.frame.width * 0.15
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.contentView.snp_centerX)
            make.width.equalTo(self.contentView.snp_width)
            make.top.equalTo(self.snp_top)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.snp_bottom)
        }
        contentView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(self.snp_center)
        }

        let shareImage = UIImage(named: "share-moment")
        shareButton.setImage(shareImage, forState: .Normal)
        shareButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapShareButton", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        shareButton.enabled = false
        shareButton.alpha = 0.0
        imageView.addSubview(shareButton)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        shareButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            let size = CGSizeMake(shareButtonLength, shareButtonLength)
            var offset = shareButtonLength / 2
            if let imageLength = shareImage?.size.height {
                offset = (shareButtonLength - imageLength) / 2
            }

            make.bottom.equalTo(self.imageView).multipliedBy(0.95).offset(offset)
            make.right.equalTo(self.imageView).multipliedBy(0.95).offset(offset)
            make.size.equalTo(size)
        }
        setupSlidingDrawer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil

        exitDeleteMode()
    }

    func enableSharing() {
        shareButton.enabled = true
        shareButton.alpha = 1.0
    }

    func didTapShareButton() {
        shareCallback?()
    }

    func setupSlidingDrawer() {
        let deleteView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.frame.width - drawerWidth, self.frame.origin.y, drawerWidth, self.frame.height))
        deleteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let deleteGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        deleteGradientLayer.frame = deleteView.bounds
        deleteGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(hex: 0xE8557C).CGColor, UIColor(hex: 0xCC2B49).CGColor]
        deleteView.layer.insertSublayer(deleteGradientLayer, atIndex: 0)

        let trashButton = UIButton()
        trashButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trash_can"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        trashButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didPressDelete"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        deleteView.addSubview(trashButton)
        deleteView.bringSubviewToFront(trashButton)

        trashButton.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(deleteView.snp_center)
            make.width.equalTo(deleteView.snp_width).multipliedBy(0.354)
            make.height.equalTo(deleteView.snp_height).multipliedBy(0.07)
        })
        contentView.addSubview(deleteView)

        deleteView.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(self.imageView.snp_right)
            make.height.equalTo(self.contentView.snp_height)
            make.width.equalTo(drawerWidth)
        })
        addGestureRecognizers()
    }

    func addGestureRecognizers() {
        let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("didSwipeCell:"))
        swipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .Left
        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
    }


class MomentsViewController: ContainerSubController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var moments: [Moment] = []
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let headerIdentifier = "headerCellIdentifier"
    let headerLabelText = "Moments"
    let headerCellHeight: CGFloat = 103.0
    let noMomentsLabelText = "It's looking pretty empty in here! Assign a Moments action (Share Moment To Twitter) to a Hot Key to get started."
    let noMomentsReuseIdentifier = "NoMoments"
    var currentSwipedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        collectionView.registerClass(MomentsViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MomentsViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: noMomentsReuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(view)
            make.width.equalTo(view)
            make.center.equalTo(view)
        }
        setupTransitionToMainButton()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refreshMoments()
        collectionView.reloadData()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleMomentSavedNotifcation", name: MomentNotifcation.MomentSaved.rawValue, object: nil)

    }

    //MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let momentsViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(MomentsViewCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MomentsViewCell, moment = moments[safe:indexPath.row] else {
                return MomentsViewCell()
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your guard, make sure to return `momentsViewCell`, the one you dequeued before.

for example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  if let momentsViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(MomentsViewCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MomentsViewCell {
   return momentsViewCell
  else {
   return MomentsViewCell()
   }
```

**Edit**

As I see the screenshots, the log is warning about optimizations. The whole assignment might not work because the variable is not used later on.

Comment: This is one of the first things we tried as we thought that their was no reference to the cell and that's what was causing its release but it did not work.

The release is happening when the collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier -> init(). So it is being released before the variable is being initialized.

Comment: Can you elaborate (and remove the not useful images from your question while you edit it) on what exactly you did and what the outcome was? Also, it's quite unusual to have subviews not being `weak`. I'm unsure, if that is okay nowerdays or probably related.

Comment: we removed the guard and assigned the moment cell directly using:

    if let momentsViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(MomentsViewCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MomentsViewCell {

Also as far as weak subViews, we are not using outlets so they are not needed. Although now that your mention it on a completely unrelated note the delegate var should be weak,